# How to streaming from Raspberry PI 4 to Android

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, camera, vlc, raspberry-pi4

Hello I am developing a mobile application and I wanted to put a screen on it for users to be able to access / view the contents of my camera that is connected to the Raspberry. For that I used VLC. However, I managed to stream from the side of the Raspberry and I can access the camera on my personal PC, but when I try to access Android Studio, it simply loads and gives me an error like "Impossible to load the video".
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: `when I try to access Android Studio, ` ? You should try to access the stream from the raspi.

Comment: Hello! No but i can access the camera from VLC of my PC. However, I dont how to access from Android Studio!

Comment: `How to streaming from Raspberry PI 4 to Android` AND `dont how to access from Android Studio!` do not match! What is it what you want?

Comment: I would think you wanted to write an Android app that could read and display the stream coming from the raspi.

Comment: yes thats what I want